# Get "Can Window Be Resized"?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I looked around the documents for WinAPI and stackoverflow and all I could find for pulling window information was `WINDOWINFO` which does not include whether the window is resizable or not. All I'm looking for is the boolean value of whether or not the window has resizable borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally infer this from the border style, which is part of the `dwStyle` member of the `WINDOWINFO` struct. For example, windows with a style `WS_THICKFRAME` can be resized.

Comment: They can generally be resized, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: You don't really need the WINDOWINFO for that: `bool isWindowResizable = ( GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_STYLE ) & WS_THICKFRAME ) != 0;`